# Spark Scala Aggregation

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I am trying to convert the below sql to spark scala api.

```
select beg_dt, col1, col2, count(distinct col3)
from tbl
group by 1 ,2,3
union all 
select beg_dt, col1, "xyx" as col2 ,count(distinct col3)
from tbl
group by 1,2
union all
select beg_dt, "abc" as col1, "xyx" as col2 , count(distinct col3)
from tbl
group by 1
```

Basically aggregating at each dimension level.

Trying to build a list and iterate through it as below but I am unable to add the static column in each pass.

```
val dimCols: List[List[String]] =  List(
  List("col1", "col2" ), 
  List("col1", "'xyx' as col2"), 
  List("'abc' as col1","'xyx' as col2"  )
) 

val df = for (dimCol <- dimCols) yield { val x = myDF.groupBy( ( $"beg_dt" +: dimCol ).map(col): _* ).
                                                         agg(
                                                             countDistinct($"col4").as("count"),
                            
                               )
                        x       
              }
```

Any pointers on how to get this done cleanly?

Comment: Can you post a little bit more of your code? I neither see any Spark nor an attempt to iterate a list

Comment: Added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

When developing code for clients, I tried to use Spark SQL since everyone knows it.  Just read in the file as a dataframe and convert to a temporary view.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/sql-programming-guide.html

Lets make believe you data is in the bronze directory of the mounted data lake and it is named "your_data.parquet".

```
//
//  1 - read file and convert to spark session view
//

// read into df
path = "/mnt/lake/bronze/your_data.parquet"
val df1 = spark.read.format("parquet").load(path)

// convert to view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("your_tbl")
```

The next step is to execute your Spark SQL.  The results are returned as a dataframe.

```
//
//  2 - execute sql and get df
//

// make sql string
val stmt = """
  select beg_dt, col1, col2, count(distinct col3)
  from your_tbl
  group by 1 ,2,3

  union all 

  select beg_dt, col1, "xyx" as col2 ,count(distinct col3)
  from your_tbl
  group by 1,2

  union all

  select beg_dt, "abc" as col1, "xyx" as col2 , count(distinct col3)
  from your_tbl
  group by 1
"""

// execute sql
val df2 = spark.sql(stmt)

// show results
display(df2)
```

In short, convert files to temporary views (tables) and use SQL.  I can not be simpler!

Comment: Already have it in this format, which i am trying to convert using scala dataframe api

Comment: You need to have three data frame variables, one for each select.  Then union.  Its not hard.  However, I do not have any sample data.

Comment: wanted to avoid that as i have 5 more unions in my code with similar aggregations

Answer (score 0):

This code can be converted into a function.  The important thing is that the structure of the returned results has to be the same!

```
// My list of queries
val queries_lst = List(
 
 """
 select variety,  max(`sepal.length`) as max_length, max(`sepal.width`) as max_width
 from iris 
 where variety = 'Versicolor'
 group by variety
 """,

 """
 select variety,  max(`sepal.length`) as max_length, max(`sepal.width`) as max_width
 from iris 
 where variety = 'Virginica'
 group by variety
 """,

 """
 select variety,  max(`sepal.length`) as max_length, max(`sepal.width`) as max_width
 from iris 
 where variety = 'Setosa'
 group by variety
 """,
  
)

// execute quries
val results_ary = queries_lst.map(spark.sql)

// empty data frame
var union_df = results(0)

// for each result, union to empty data frame
results_ary.slice(1, results.size).foreach((dataframe)=>{
  union_df = union_df.union(dataframe)
})

// Show the union of results
union_df.show()
```

I am going to use the iris dataset that is famous in data science. It has been loaded in databricks as a Hive Table.

[image]

I want to aggregate by all three varieties and union the results.  Of course this can be done easily by removing the where clause.  But then I would not have 3 separate queries.

The map function prepares the statements to execute.  The slice and for each allow you to append the results of each execution.  The .show() statement forces the whole code to execute.

In short, my resulting dataframe has the results of the three separate queries.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Could you try building a rollup to aggregate on the different levels? Then you would need to fill the null values from the rollup.

It might look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

val resultDF = inputDF.rollup($"beg_dt", $"col_1", $"col_2"). 
                       agg(countDistinct($"col_3")).
                       na.fill(Map(
                          "col_1" -> "abc", 
                          "col_2" -> "xyz"
                       ))
```

Sorry for the formatting, I'm still trying to figure out SO

Relevant documentation for [rollup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#rollup(col1:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset)
Relevant documentation for [fillna](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#fill(valueMap:Map%5BString,Any%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

Comment: I don't think this will work with multiple Spark SQL stmts.

Comment: The whole point is you don't need multiple Spark SQL statements. The rollup does exactly what he is trying to do without the unions.